# Xamarin forms project getting incorrect native digits from framework

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, localization

I'm trying to localize my Xamarin forms app and I noticed that my datetimes were not being localized. When I inspected the culture info object, I noticed the NativeDigits array was populated with English digits.

This is what I get in my Xamarin project

[image: This is what I get in my Xamarin project]

This is what it should look like

[image: This is what it should look like]

**Edit:**

I have sample application which demonstrates this. It's basically a fork from [this](https://xamgirl.com/handle-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms-without-any-plugin/) article.

https://github.com/raihaniqbal/MultilingualXFSample

```cs
var language = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures).ToList().First(element => element.EnglishName.Contains(picker.SelectedItem.ToString()));
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = language;
```

**Edit 2:**

I've come up with this temporary workaround. I've stored the native digits in the resx file and I parse the datetime string this way:

```cs
private string ToLocalizedTimeString(string englishTimeString)
{
     var localizedTimeString = String.Join("", englishTimeString.Select(x =>
     {
                if ("1234567890".Contains(x.ToString()))
                    return AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(x.ToString());
                else
                    return x.ToString();
     }));

     localizedTimeString = localizedTimeString.Replace("AM", AppResources.AM);

     localizedTimeString = localizedTimeString.Replace("PM", AppResources.PM);

     return localizedTimeString;
}
```

Comment: Glad you came up with an approach! I recommend making that an "answer" instead of editing it into your "question". That makes it clearer that it is a solution, for anyone else who comes along. And given that it is the solution you are using, after 48 hours you can accept it as the answer - so everyone looking at open questions will know that you are no longer seeking an answer.

Comment: This is just a temporary workaround and doesnt answer my original question. I'm still looking for an answer. I dont plan on using this solution in production tbh. I have used date/time in heaps of places throughout my application.

Comment: OK. Then the "answer" presumably is that it is a bug/limitation of the underlying XForms code that generates that CultureInfo. Definitely worth a bug report. Have you tested on a physical device that is set to Arabic?  Wondering if it is somehow a wrong flag inside emulator, causing it to always use Western digits, or really is in XForms itself. Also can you test on both iOS and Android?

Comment: Yep tested on a physical device that is set to Arabic. Haven't tested on iOS yet.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to make a custom CultureInfo with the desired digits.

1. Clone the Arabic culture using [`CultureInfo.Clone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone?view=net-5.0):

```
CultureInfo ci1 = ...whatever you do now to get arabic culture info...
CultureInfo ci2 = (CultureInfo) ci1.Clone();
```

2. Now you have a writeable NumberFormat. Set its digits to the desired characters.

```
// Put the desired unicode chars in these 10 strings.
ci2.NumberFormat.NativeDigits = {"", "١", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
```

3. Use `ci2` as current CultureInfo.

Comment: This is one of the temporary workarounds (including the one I added) that I might have to resort to until I figure out why the framework is behaving this way. Might open a ticket.